# PHP Рow to remove a single value from row?

Tags: php, row

**code:**

```
$str = 'test2$test2$test3$test3$test4';
$id = 'test2';
```

We need to find the value of **$id** and remove **$test2** or **test2$** depending on the position **test2** in the string ;

To search using:

```
$substr_count1 = substr_count ($str, '$test2');
$substr_count2 = substr_count ($str, 'test2$');
if ($substr_count1> 0) {
//if exist $test2 then need delete single value $test2 from row and row will be
// $str = 'test2$test3$test3$test4'
// find the value of $test2
// how to remote one value $test2
}
elseif ($substr_count2> 0) {
//if exist test2$ then need delete single value test2$ from row and row will be
// $str = 'test2$test3$test3$test4'
// find the value of test2$
// how to remote one value test2$
}
```

how to remove a single value?

Comment: why you have data in such format? Consider using arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the first occurence of the '$test2' if exists, if not, replace the first occurence of 'test$':

```
$str = 'test2$test2$test3$test3$test4';
$id = 'test2';

$position1=strpos($str,'$'.$id);
$position2=strpos($str,$id.'$');

//if the first occurence is the '$test2':
if($position1<$position2)
{
$str= preg_replace('/'.'\$'.$id.'/', '', $str, 1);
}
//If the first occurence is the 'test$'
else
{
$str= preg_replace('/'.$id.'\$'.'/', '', $str, 1);
}

echo $str;
```

Comment: me need delete one value only! only one value test2$ or only one value $test2

Comment: In your example, what whould be the final string after replacement?

Comment: if exist test2$ then $str = 'test2$test3$test3$test4'

Comment: if exist $test2 then $str = 'test2$test3$test3$test4'

Comment: The example you just gave me has the same result!

Comment: but what will be if $test or test$ not exist in row?

Comment: Yes i agree, it will replace 'nothing' one time. I'm trying to understand what you want at first. @LeoLoki

Comment: if exist text2$ need remote one value text2$ elseif if exist $text2 need remote one value $text2..  but its comment only) I modified the code for my. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You `explode()` the string, remove the elements, and `implode()` it back together:

```
$str = 'test2$test2$test3$test3$test4';
$id = 'test2';

$array = explode('$', $str);

$result = implode('$', array_diff($array, array($id)));

var_dump($result);
```

#### Read More:

- [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode)
- [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode)
- [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff)